# Finding a general form of $ \frac{d^{2n}}{dk^{2n}}\frac{1}{k} \sin(k)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to solve the general form of  $$ \frac{d^{2n}}{dk^{2n}}\frac{1}{k} \sin(k)$$ using the general Leibniz rule but im getting confused while calculating it. Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may just use the standard results, for $ x\neq0$,
$$
\frac{d^{p}}{dx^{p}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{(-1)^pp!}{x^{p+1}}, \quad \frac{d^{p}}{dx^{p}}\left(\sin x\right)=\sin\left(x+\frac{p\pi}2 \right)
$$ giving, with the Leibniz rule,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)&=\sum_{p=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}p\frac{(-1)^pp!}{x^{p+1}}\sin\left(x+\frac{(2n-p)\pi}2 \right)
\\\\&=\sum_{p=0}^{2n}\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-p)!}\frac{(-1)^{n+p}}{x^{p+1}}\sin\left(x-\frac{p\pi}2 \right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thank you. i also managed to arrive at this result.

Comment: is there a closed form for this?